# Velocity operator for a Hamiltonian that satisfies the generalized Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The velocity operator is defined as $\mathbf{v}=i[H,\mathbf{r}]$ for the Hamiltonian $H$ satisfying $H\psi=\epsilon \psi$. This can be obtained from the Ehrenfest theorem. I'm wondering if $\mathbf{v}=i[H,\mathbf{r}]$ still holds for $H$ satisfying the generalized Schrodinger equation $H\psi=\epsilon S\psi$, where $S$ is the overlap operator?

Comment: +1. But where do you get that this only works if $H\psi = \epsilon \psi$ ?

Answer (score 6):

Consider a time-independent operator $\mathbf{r}$, its expectation value, and the time derivative of the expectation value (by applying the product rule for derivatives):

\begin{align}
\tag{1}
\langle \mathbf{r}\rangle &\equiv \int \psi^* \mathbf{r}\psi \,\,\, dr\\
\frac{\rm{d}}{\textrm{d}t}\langle \mathbf{r}\rangle &= \int \left(\frac{\rm{d}}{\textrm{d}t}\psi^*\right) \mathbf{r}\psi \,dr + \int  \psi^* \mathbf{r}\left(\frac{\rm{d}}{\textrm{d}t}\psi\right)\,dr\tag{2}. 
\end{align}

Now let's plug in the Schrödinger equation (with $\hbar=1$ since that's what you had) and its conjugate:

\begin{align}\tag{3}
\frac{\rm{d}}{\textrm{d}t}\psi &= -\textrm{i}H\psi \\
\frac{\rm{d}}{\textrm{d}t}\psi^* &= \textrm{i}H\psi^*. \tag{4}\\
\end{align}

The result is:

\begin{align}
\frac{\rm{d}}{\textrm{d}t}\langle \mathbf{r}\rangle &= \int \left(\textrm{i}H\psi^* \right) \mathbf{r}\psi \,dr + \int  \psi^* \mathbf{r}\left(-\textrm{i}H\psi \right)\,dr\tag{5}  \\
\langle \mathbf{v}\rangle &\equiv\textrm{i} \left[H ,\langle \mathbf{r}\rangle   \right].\tag{6}
\end{align}

I never explicitly mentioned anyhting about eigenvalues and never used $H\psi = \epsilon\psi$ or $H\psi = \epsilon S \psi$: I just used:

- the definition of an expectation value $\langle \cdot \rangle$,
- the product rule for derivatives,
- the Schrödinger equation (see the derivation of the Schrödinger equation in Section 2.2 of [this PDF](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_05F13_Chap_06.pdf) to see why this is the equation of motion for $\psi$ if we want its norm to be preserved as Born's rule relates wavefunction norms to probabilities: i.e. unitary evolution), so we have used:

  - Born's rule,
  - the law that probabilities must sum up to 1,
- the definitions:

  - $\langle \mathbf{v}\rangle \equiv \frac{\rm{d}}{\textrm{d}t}\langle \mathbf{r}\rangle$,
  - $[A,B] \equiv AB-BA$,
  - $\textrm{i}^2=-1.$

On page 20 of the same [aforementioned PDF](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_05F13_Chap_06.pdf) you can see how the Heisenberg equation of motion is derived, if you want to do something similar without expectation values.

Comment: By the definition of an expectation value, you are assuming orthogonal wave functions, right? How about nonorthogonal wave functions? $\langle \mathbf{r} \rangle = {\langle \psi|\mathbf{r}| \psi\rangle  /  \langle \psi|\mathbf{S}| \psi\rangle }$

Comment: For nonorthogonal wave functions, Eq. 3 turns out to be $id\psi / dt = S^{-1}H\psi$ ?